# Not able to run “sudo” after rebooting my Odroid-C2 system running Ubuntu 20?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, root

I was happily working on my Ubuntu when suddenly — after a reboot — I realised I cannot longer invoke `sudo` nor `root`. Basically, this is what I get no matter what:

```
lui@odroid:~$ su root
su: Authentication failure
lui@odroid:~$ su odroid
su: Authentication failure
lui@odroid:~$ sudo ls
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

I can SSH with my user account but I cannot use `sudo` which becomes very hard thing to fix.

I have checked and I am still in the `sudoers` group:

```
lui@odroid:~$ grep '^sudo:.*$' /etc/group | cut -d: -f4
odroid,lui
```

Unfortunately I cannot boot from a USB flash drive; the device is an [Odroid-C2](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-c2/odroid-c2) board running Ubuntu 20.

Could anything be done to fix this?

Comment: Odd. Have you tried any of the stuff here to see if you lost sudo rights or somehow were removed from the sudo user’s group? https://ostechnix.com/find-sudo-users-linux-system/

Comment: “Unfortunately I cannot boot from a USB flash drive…” Why is that? I see the device has four USB ports. It simply disallows USB flash drive booting?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I think so. The bootloader code needs to be on emmc/sd. The kernel/boot.ini probably as well.

Answer (score 0):

Of-course anything is fixable but its a bit difficult to advise how without knowing what you did, your environment or is variant.

If you have console access you can usually get full root access to your system by rebooting and then modifying the grub boot up by adding init=/bin/bash which will load you into a bash shell and allow you to correct the issue.

Similarly, you can boot with a USB disk and then mount the existing disk to make repairs.

The first thing to do is to set a password for root - If you are using a USB key, after mounting your disk - depending in your skill level - you may need to do a command like "chroot /mntpoint" so you are working with the live filesystem. Do a "passwd root" to change the root password. You can then reboot and log in as root.

Alternatively, Add your public key to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys and modify /etc/sshd.conf to allow root logins. Once you reboot (or equivalent) you should be able to SSH as root@ip.add.RR to get in as root and then start repairing the problem.

You should also look at /etc/groups to make sure you are still a member of the appropriate group(s) - normally adm,admin and/or wheel.  Also check /etc/sudoers and ensure there is an appropriate line to allow you/your group to escalate your privs.

Comment: It is hard for me to say what I did, I did not do anything more than playing with `nginx` and `apache2` servers.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the grub boot option, please?